# Is it possible to rearrange this equation to solve for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$0 = -i+(iq-ix+1)\ln(1+i)-(1-d)^xln(1+i)-(1-d)^xln(1-d)+t (1-d)^xln(1+i)+t \ln(1-d)^x$$

Variables $i, q, d, t, x$

Wanting to rearrange equation for $x$, online calculators don't seem to like it.

Comment: with $*$ you mean multiplication?

Comment: @MarMik Correct

Comment: simplify the logs with rules of logarithms first

Comment: Your expression is ambiguous as we don't known for sure what are the arguments of the logs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Apologies for the ambiguity. Should be fixed now, the backside multipliers on some of the logs were meant to be part of the coefficients.

Comment: I believe it is impossible to solve algebraically now, as it contains both linear and exponential terms.

Answer (score 2):

We assume here that $\ln(x)(y) = \ln(xy)$ to clear up ambiguity. Let $1 - d = d'$ to simplify things. First, we will use $\ln(xy) = \ln(x) + \ln(y)$:

$$0 = -i + (iq - ix + 1)\ln(1 + i) - \ln(1 + i) - \ln(d'^{x}) - \ln(d'^{x + 1}) + t\ln(1 + i) +t\ln(d'^{x}) + t\ln(d'^{x})$$

Using the closely related property that $\ln(x^{y}) = y\ln(x)$, and also grouping like terms:

$$0 = -i + (iq - ix + t)\ln(1 + i) + (2tx - 2x - 1)\ln(d')$$

Isolating terms with $x$ on one side:

$$i - (iq + it)\ln(1 + i) + \ln(d') = -ix\ln(1 + i) + (2tx - 2x)\ln(d')$$

$$i - (iq + it)\ln(1 + i) + \ln(d') = ((2t - 2)\ln(d') - i\ln(1 + i))x$$

Isolating $x$:

$$x = \frac{i - (iq + it)\ln(1 + i) + \ln(d')}{(2t - 2)\ln(d') - i\ln(1 + i)}$$

Substituting back $d' = 1 - d$:

$$\boxed{x = \frac{i - (iq + it)\ln(1 + i) + \ln(1-d)}{(2t - 1)\ln(1 -d) - i\ln(1 + i)}}$$

You could use the log rules to bring the coefficients into the logarithms and then combine them, but it doesn't really matter for purposes of calculation.

Let me know if I have made any mistakes.

Comment: How can you be sure of the meaning of $\log(a)(b)$ ?

Comment: With the coefficients already in front of the logarithms, it wouldn't make very much sense to multiply them on the back side as well.

Comment: You are right, one of the terms has both, but who knows.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Sorry, I misled you by the way my terms were constructed. $clog(a)(b)$ is meant to be $cblog(a)$. Should be fixed now in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve for $x$ with the usual functions, as $x$ appears both as a linear term and an exponential.

Comment: Numerical solutions are probably the best you will be able to get. Try starting with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method